# Can't save time frame end date for education entry

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I currently have two entries for the education. But one of them refuses to store an end date.

- deselect the `I am currently a student` box.
- edit the entry, and select a year from the drop down box
- press `save`, The box changes its state to `Saving` before the entry collapses

The entry still shows `current` and when I refresh the page and edit the entry again the end year of the time frame is not set.

Answer (score 1):

This should be fixed. Thanks for letting us know!